# Using hasOwnproperty() in a nested object

Tags: javascript

I have the following data:

```
trace = {
  "name":"foo",
  "dataref": {
    "xdata":"n",
    "ydata":"m"
  }
};
```

I would like to check if the object has the property ydata but if I run the following command, it returns 'false'. Can you please help me with the correct syntax?

```
console.log(trace.hasOwnProperty(trace.dataref.ydata));
```

https://jsbin.com/jamohurota/edit?html,js,console

Comment: [`trace.dataref.hasOwnProperty('ydata')`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/0d6rpoj7/)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are calling hasOwnProperty on trace, then that is the object that will be checked. You need to call it on the object that you suspect has the property:

```
    trace.dataref.hasOwnProperty("ydata");
```